# selenium, py. <div> имеет элемент <tree>. При разворачивании дерева у элемента появляется скролл_барр. Как скролить такую страницу

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, прокрутка, switch

На странице, при клике на ссылку, появляется div в котором есть Tree. При разворачивании дерева, в элементе появляется скролл бар. Добраться до скроллбара увы не могу.
Перепробовал много разных способов, как проскролить до нужного элемента. 
Проблема в том, что дерево большее, а элемент не в самом конце дерева. Следовательно это надо сделать циклом. 
Как это сделать, увы не совсем понимаю. 
Желательно расписать подробней...
Спасибо...

```
  //float-panel class="a"
  //div class="b"
  //tree class='c'
```

Скролл бар не выделяется как веб элемент

Comment: Добро пожаловать на stackoverflow! не могли бы прикрепить пример, чтобы можно было дать точный ответ? нажмите на править и добавьте html или ссылку на страницу, где можно это воспроизводить.

Answer (score 0):

Решение такое...

```
def X(driver):
    def currentOffset():
        return driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('.filter__tree').scrollTop;")

    def viewPortHeight():
        return driver.execute_script(
            "return document.querySelector('.filter__tree').getBoundingClientRect().height")

    def scrollTo(offset):
        driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('.filter__tree').scrollTop = %s" % offset)

    totalHeight = driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('.tree-root').getBoundingClientRect().height")

    while True:
        print('screenshot')
        time.sleep(2)
        scrollTo(currentOffset() + viewPortHeight())
        if (currentOffset() >= totalHeight - viewPortHeight()):
            break
```